# WooCommerce: How to disable redirect, if the table is empty so as to keep an empty table

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am quite new to **Woocommerce**, however i do find the plugin very interesting, one thing that i would like to know is:

- When on **cart-page**, if you were to empty the `table` via:
- `WC()->cart->empty_cart()`
  **OR**
- `foreach` item in the `table`:
  `WC()->cart->set_quantity("cart_item_key_id" , 0)`

You would get **redirected** to the `"Cart is empty"` display where only this message is displayed. The `table` would however disappear and also not be part of the `DOM`.

---

### Question

How to make sure that the `table` remains in the place even if it doesn't have any items ? Or **alternatively** while having an `child-theme` with all the files, one example: `your-theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`, how to, while being on the **cart-page** and seeing the "cart is empty" message, modify the `cart.php` so, add an item **programmtically** and regenerate the `table`.

---

### What i tried

Removed the woocommerce_cart_is_empty message via
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty', 'wc_empty_cart_message', 10 );` which was added to `functions.php` file.

It did remove the message, however it didnt fix the problem, that the `table` is also gone.
[Cart-page without the "cart is empty" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsawY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in functions.php file.

```
   function disable_empty_table_redirect() {
        if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product()) {
            $products = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
            if (!$products->have_posts()) {
                remove_action('template_redirect', 'wc_template_redirect');
            }
        }
    }
    
    add_action('template_redirect', 'disable_empty_table_redirect');
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the table is still gone